# Does JIRA have a better way to compare texts beyond "Activity History"?

Tags: jira, user-stories, version-control

When someone in Trac change the text of a Ticket, we can see easily the modification by clicking on Diff link and them it displays visualy by highlighting the removed and added words/characters (red for removed and green for added).

Example: https://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/6943

And JIRA display the old and new version of text modification with no visual help like Trac. There's only the raw text.

Example: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira062/viewing-an-issue-s-change-history-588581717.html

I am using the plugin "compare" of notepad++ to do so.

Is there a work around for this to work like Trac?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about project management tooling without any reference to testing. These questions are better asked on http://pm.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Not really.. You could always:

- Write your own history tab.
- Amend your email templates for better
  formatting (I have to agree with you on that one - the default emails
  are useful to get as a note that something has changed, but I don't
  know anyone who really reads them because the formatting is not
  friendly). See
  http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Customising+Email+Content